# How do I merge these two array's containing hashes into a third array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have two array's containing hashes with product information. The array's are not sorted in a meaningful way.

**Array A** (number of products/hashes = 27.605) contains:

- itemId
- description
- *category*

example

```
[
  {"itemId" => "wi225858",
   "description" => "Awesome product",
   "category" => "/Top products/"},
  {...}
]
```

**Array B** (number of products/hashes = 18.498) contains:

- itemId
- description
- *brand*

example

```
[
  {"itemId" => "wi225858",
   "description" => "Awesome product",
   "brand" => "Coolio"},
  {...}
]
```

**Goal** (number of products/hashes = 27.605):

- itemId
- description
- category
- brand

example

```
[
  {"itemId" => "wi225858",
   "description" => "Awesome product",
   "category" => "/Top products/",
   "brand" => "Coolio"},
  {...},
  {"itemId" => "wi225605",
   "description" => "Brandless nice product",
   "category" => "/Nice products/"},
  {...}
]
```

The `itemId`'s are unique. I want the Ruby code to take an `itemId` from A, check if B contains a product with the same `itemId`, if it does, add the `brand` value to the item. If no `brand` is found, then leave it empty.

The code should create a new array with product hashes I can save to a JSON file.

I've tried:

```
c = []

a.each do |one|
  b.each do |two|
    if one['itemId'] == two['itemId']
      combined_product = one.merge(two)

      c << combined_product
    end
  end
end
```

I have two problems with this code:

1. `c.size` returns 21.022, which means there are 6.583 products without a `brand` that have not made it into array `c`.
2. It's slow

What could I try next?

Comment: The inner block is executed 27,605 × 18,498 = 510,637,290 times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010582/joining-arrays-of-hashes-in-ruby) shows a simple way:

```
(a+b).group_by { |product| product["itemId"] }.map { |k,v| v.inject(:merge) }
```

Here is how it works:

1. We make one big array with all products
2. We group together products with the same `itemId`
3. Finally we loop and map to merge same products hashes

Answer (score 1):

There is a design flaw. You should have hashes instead of arrays like

```
A = {
  "wi225858" => {
    "description" => "Awesome product",
    "category" => "/Top products/"
   },
  ...
}
```

and

```
B = {
  "wi225858" => {
    "description" => "Awesome product",
    "brand" => "Coolio"
  },
  ...
}
```

Then, you can simply do

```
A.merge(B){|_, a, b| a.merge(b)}
```

Even considering the time it takes to convert your arrays into the hashes I suggest, it should run magnitudes faster than what you are doing now.